# Multiple Elements with same custom directive vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives, custom-directive

**Hey there,** I have some elements with the same custom directive but different values in my page.

I want to get all elements with that directive to process on them.

When I use this code:

```js
Vue.directive('can', function (value) {
    console.log(value)
})
```

it just gave me the first element with the `can` directive, not all of them, so how I can get all of the elements with the `can` directive?!

Update:
my elements are like so:

```html
<button v-can="'register-permission'">Register</button>
<button v-can="'buy-permission'">Buy</button>
<button v-can="'Sell-permission'">Sell</button>
```

I want to access all buttons with the `v-can` directive in page! How can it be done?

Comment: I think you will need to have the directive keep a registry of elements.

Comment: as @RoyJ pointed out, do something like this: `let cans = [];
Vue.directive('can', {
    inserted: function (el, binding) {
      cans.push({el: el, value: binding.value})
      console.log(JSON.stringify(cans))
    }
})`

Comment: I know this sounds stupid and does't make alot of sense.. But what happens if you put an unique [key](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) on each of the buttons? - Maybe Vue is trying to re-use your button wrongly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Sphinx , oh still just give me first element which uses can!, cause i want to get updated directive on listener, something like this: `Bus.$on('permissionChanged', function (data) {
 let cans = []
 Vue.directive('can', function (el, binding, vnode) {
  cans.push(el)
  console.log(cans)
 })
})`

Answer (score 0):

Following Vuejs documentation on [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments), I would access all of them like this:

```
Vue.directive('can', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    console.log(binding.expression)
  }
})
```